# Django Error while trying to migrate model on Postgre DB

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm still learning to use Django and I have an issue while trying to create a model.
Here's my models.py

```
class Identifiants(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
taxon = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
noms = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
fiche = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
comestible = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
sms = models.NullBooleanField()
a_imprimer = models.NullBooleanField()
lieu = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
apparition = models.TextField()

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'identifiants'
```

The makemigrations command works with no issues but the migrate one is where I have problems

```
Running migrations:
Applying app.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, 
in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.DataError: NUMERIC precision 65535 must be between 1 and 1000
LINE 1: ...iants" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "taxon" numeric(65...
```

I'm using IntegerField method so I can't see why there is an issue ...

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` id is automatically created by django.

check it [here](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/211), its similar to your question.

Comment: Working ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @raziakhan But  what to do if i have to set one-to-many link?

Comment: Hi. I have the same error, but I do not have the field id to remove. How can I correct it?